# Giving rep for featured image?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, featured-photo

How does the community feel about giving a rep bonus to the winners of the Weekly Featured Image thread?

Answer (score 36):

I've waffled on this thought... In some ways, I think I like it because we're a visual community and, as such, your work is part of your real reputation. In other ways, I'm not entirely sure, because the site is a Q&A site and that isn't really a part of it.

The one thought that I had on that was actually to use badges instead. Not sure how easy it is to badge on the main site from a selection on the meta, but something like an "Artist" silver badge (with multiple support) would be a cool prize for sure and give you a little more permanence in terms of visible recognition after the week has passed.

Comment: +1 - for a badge

Comment: +1 for a badge!

Comment: +1 for a badge -- that would be perfect.

Comment: I also +1'ed for the badge idea. I'd like to suggest that there be a bronze, silver, and gold badge :-). Bronze might be for submitting and getting an upvote. silver you have to win. Gold you have to win by some large amount or win a certain number of times?

Comment: @Tom: Perhaps something like that might work, but it'd have to fleshed out a bit more...

Comment: @Pearsonartphoto: absolutely. I was being purposefully vague :-).

Comment: Yeah, I'd definitely be more badge than rep. I mean, getting your photo on the front page is a pretty good reward in itself. I'm not sure how the badge thing would function technically - if it requires mod intervention I'm not sure that corresponds with the 'spirit' of badges which seem to be mostly 'calculatable'...

Comment: It seems like there was solid support for some kind of badge (or badge system) for this, but the idea also seems to have died here. Is there any progress on coming up with something for this?

Comment: Copper badge for entering; silver badge for winning.

Comment: @mattdm that seems way too generous -- I'd suggest a bronze badge on the main site for each win, and maybe a bronze badge on mea for "have ever entered". Not sure how it'd be implemented though, as the software is mostly shared across the SE network.

Comment: Copper badge for entering the first time only, but I think a silver badge on the main site is definitely appropriate for each win. This is, after all, something only one person can get in a week.

Comment: Perhaps a gold badge for winning a certain number of times in a year?

Answer (score 10):

It would be nice to somehow have continuing recognition of these images, without having to dig through all the old voting threads (which can still be voted on, so the highest-voted can change).

Can we create a page that simply shows all the featured images in a nice format in reverse chronological order, and link to it from the area to the right of the image?

Answer (score 4):

I like the badge idea, but after a discussion with our developers, we've decided that we will not be creating this feature in the immediate future. It would involve some major changes that we're not ready to implement right now, but we will keep this in mind for any future changes made to the badge creation and awarding system.

Comment: EN req ticket pile :)

Comment: Aww... OK then.